# Implode array for query passing, only returning one value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to implode an array of IDs ( and I know that this array should be holding 16 IDs) so that I can pass a comma separated string to a query.

I have this now:

```
foreach ($daily as &$d) {
$ids = [];

if ($d->date > $condition){
  $d->employee = 'hired';
  $ids[] = $d->empNum;
  dd($ids);
}
print_r($ids);

$empIDs = implode(" ", $ids);

endforeach
```

and the `dd($ids)` successfully dumps the first ID, but that one only.

How should I loop this and properly implode it so that I can pass it to a querY?

Comment: `and I know `. But we do not, Post complete MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: show the content of  $d->empNum ..

Comment: You show no loop and `$ids` has only one item... Is the `dd()` function an important piece of this mystery?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no I'm only using dd() to dump the array. I need to add a loop though

Comment: So, are you looking for someone to guess where your data is coming from and guess at how the loop should look like? What is `$d`?

Comment: Sorry, I added the loop that contains this code now. I also added print_r($ids); which prints arrays like so: Array( [0] => 24112 ) Array ( [0] => 24113 ), etc.

Comment: You are initializing `$ids` _within_ your loop.  So every time through you are just emptying it out.  Also, you should probably do the `implode()` _after_ the loop, not inside it.

Comment: Further, that is _still_ not your actual code, as what you have there now wouldn't even run.  You make it really hard for us to help you when you don't give us accurate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
// Declare this outside the loop so that we do not keep overwriting it
$ids = [];

foreach($daily as &$d)
{
    if($d->date > $condition)
    {
        $d->employee = 'hired';
        $ids[] = $d->empNum;
        dd($ids);
    }
    print_r($ids);
}  // Make sure to properly close the foreach construct because endforeach should be causing errors

// Generate a comma-separated list of IDs
$empIDs = implode(",", $ids);
```

Comment: Ok that solved it perfectly! Thanks so much and sorry for the confusion earlier. I see why it was screwing up obviously